# Substitute characters and truncate Email using ***

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do one code an email, say, alibaba@gmail.com to a***a@g***l.c*m in ruby on rails?

I found this when I tried to recover my password to my gmail account.

Comment: You'd write some Ruby code. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the email already split into `address` and `domain` this is much easier. But to do that its simply:

```
email = 'alibaba@gmail.com'
address, domain = email.split('@')
```

If you don't care about the character count between the first and last of each token:

```
"#{address[0]}***#{address[-1]}"
```

for the a**a before the @ and similar can be done for the domain but using split on the `.` character:

```
working_domain = domain.split('.')
"#{working_domain[0][0]}***#{working_domain[0][-1]}.#{working_domain[1][0]}*#{working_domain[1][-1]}"
```

That's a pretty ugly way to do it and its not very DRY and doesnt care about character counts. You should be able to encapsulate all of this into a function or 3 and make this simpler to use.

Answer (score 1):

From the example you give in the question ("alibaba@gmail.com" => "a***a@g***l.c*m"), it appears you don't need the number of *'s to match the number of replaced characters.  If that's the case, you can solve this with a simple regex substitution, no splitting or parsing of the address necessary:

```
email = 'alibaba@gmail.com'
email.gsub(/(?<=[\w\d])[\w\d]+(?=[\w\d])/, "**") 
# => "a**a@g**l.c**m"
```

Breaking down that regex, just for clarity: `[\w\d]+` matches strings of alphanumeric characters, excluding one alphanumeric to the left (`(?<=[\w\d])`) and another to the right (`(?=[\w\d])`) of each matched group, and replaces each match with "**".

I hope this helps.